# End of the world movie

Tags: identify-this-movie

Does anyone know the name of this Movie?. Basic plot is a virus kills nearly everyone but some survivors are in Antarctica I think. There is an earthquake predicted in USA which will trigger nuclear weapons automatically being fired everywhere including where these survivors are. The movie starts I think with a man walking back alone returning to the survivors after having disarmed the nukes. The movie is about him recalling these events. I seem to think the movie is 1970's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the film you are thinking of is [*Virus*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080768/), also known as *Day of Reckoning* from 1980.

From the IMDb synopsis:

> A film that describes the development of a deadly Virus weapons system
>   by the USA Military during the height of the Cold War epoch during the
>   early 1980's. A small group of multinational scientists stuck in the
>   Antarctic learn to survive after a human engineered virus knocks out
>   most of earth's population... ...Only about 800 people in the entire
>   world survive as General Rankin activates the ARS which is set off by
>   an earthquake in the capital Washington and not any Soviet attack,
>   thus blasting the entire world with Nuclear Armaggedon as the Soviets
>   respond with their nukes, finishing off what is left of the population
>   that managed to survive the Virus.

[image]